# make nextJS ignore a subPath in host

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

so the problem i'm having is, there is a directory in my public_html file named blog that is not related to my nextJs app, so basically after i deploy the app on host, everything works fine until i choose to check my blog part, for example the url below:

```
www.sth.com/blog
```

when i get there, i get the default next 404 page, the problem is, there is actual pages there, and i want my nodeJs server to ignore that exact route so when user goes to `www.sth.com/blog`, node app kind of ignore it and let it load the basic html pages.
i think it has something to do with my `server.js` file so here's the code in server.js
also i hosted the app on cpanel if that's important.

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const next = require('next')
 
const isDevMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT ? process.env.PORT : 3000
 
const nextjsApp = next({ dev: isDevMode })
const nextjsRequestHandler = nextjsApp.getRequestHandler()
 
nextjsApp
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    createServer((req, res) => {
      const url = new URL(req.url, "http://w.w")
      nextjsRequestHandler(req, res, url)
    }).listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
    })
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack)
    process.exit(1)
  })
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server configuration you have to check if request is meant for next or not. If not - you need to respond with your page, instead of passing request further to next:

```js
(req, res) => {
  const url = new URL(req.url, "http://w.w");
  if (/^\/blog\//.test(url.pathname)) {
    // send response with blog
  } else {
    // pass everything to Next
    nextjsRequestHandler(req, res, url);
  }
};
```

Another option would be to split next and not next in two different parts and route requests to them through reverse proxy.

Comment: i used your answere, and i wrote a simple     res.send('Hello World!') inside the if condition but i get the error Incomplete response received from application and i don't know why

Comment: Since you are using barebones server, you will have to do everything manually - attach [headers, attach body and so on](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse). You can use some application framework instead, like fastify instead of barebones node server, but this might require to change `else` part a bit. I can't give you detailed instruction since I never did this - we route everything on nginx part